# Can I call this kind of bag 'polybag'?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

[image: Smallpen plastic seed bags]
<sup>Image source: [tokopedia.com](https://www.tokopedia.com/ipb/polybag-ukuran-kecil-unt-semai-benih) (image scaled down from [original](https://ecs12.tokopedia.net/newimg/product-1/2015/1/27/284223/284223_f913d80e-a5ee-11e4-a5a1-fa892523fab8.jpg))</sup>

Can I call the bags in the image above ***polybag***? Is *polybag* an English word?

Comment: Hello! And welcome to ELL! I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. Do you want to know the origin of the word "polybag"? Or do you want to know whether it's correct to call those bags in the picture "polybags"?

Comment: @DamkerngT.: the latter "do you want to know whether it's correct to call those bags in the picture **polybags**?"

Comment: @embio Have a look [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_bag)

Comment: 37 year old native U.S. English speaker here and this is the first time I've heard this word.  Sounds like it comes from "polymer" meaning plastic, and "bag" though.

Comment: @LawrenceC and hello all, this plastic stuff is used to cultivate seeds with a mixture of compost and fertilizer. My native language absorbed it as _polybag_. If I have to create an english paper, should I use the word polymer bag or polybag?

Comment: You could say "a polypropylene (or other plastic) bag known informally as a 'polybag' " and then afterwards you can refer to it as "polybag".

Comment: @embio You're welcome. (FWIW, I might call them plastic bags or black plastic bags for planting. I think some other variations would also do. I have no specific word for it.)

Comment: Briefly looking at Google results for "gardening polybag" - I'm seeing English sites that call them plastic bags and other sites that call them "poly bags."  I think calling them "poly bags" with the space inbetween is OK.  The first time you mention them in your text I would say something like "plastic gardening bags, also known as poly bags".

Comment: Thank you all! I am just wondering if I still can post another comment here when I switch off my computer then switch on again.

Comment: There's no comment limit.

Comment: We sometimes call them [polypots](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=polypots&espv=2&biw=2377&bih=1174&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqgauwqLvJAhXLWBoKHdE0DowQsAQIRA) when used for planting seeds.

Comment: @embio, you can post another comment. The data entered here will not be deleted when the PC or the device you are using is turned off.

Answer (score 1):

I think those bags are made from polypropylene, and that's the source of the word "polybag" - however, that is not at all a common term in Australian English either (following on from @LawrenceC's comment).

Wikipedia gives some alternatives: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_bag

The most common one is "plastic bag" - though that gives the impression of something much weaker than the one in your picture.  I would recommend calling that something more specific like:

- strong plastic bag
- tough plastic bag

Answer (score 0):

[Polybag](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/polybag) is certainly a commonly used word in British English for a small plastic, usually polythene, bag.

The term is more commonly used for resealable (Ziploc) bags than open bags like those of the picture.  However, those in your picture would often be referred to as a polybag.

So, can you call those bags polybags? - Yes.